# Analayse this noun phrase

Tags: grammar, clauses

I need help to analayse the structure of noun phrase in bold letters:

"**The fact that they came back with the geolocators** was supposed to be the great success of this season"

Any suggestions? I'm quite lost, and everything I try seems wrong...

Comment: Well, my suggestion is, if the whole thing is a noun phrase: "the fact" = det. + head noun, "that they came back with the geolocators" is a postmodifier/that-clause, with S V A pattern. That = subordinate conjunction, "they"= Subject, NP, Head Noun, "came"= V, VP, Main Verb, lexical, "back" = adverb phrase, "with the geolocators" = postmodifier realized by a Prepositional phrase. "With"= Preppos. "the geolocators"= compliment of Prepos.phrase relealized by a noun phrase, with def.art and head noun.

Comment: The bit in bold is the subject of the sentence as a whole. The noun "fact" is the head, and the content clause _that they came back with the geolocators_ functions as complement of "fact". "That" is a subordinator serving as 'marker'. Within the content clause "they" is subject, and "came back with the geolocators" is the predicate. The prep "back" is complement of "came". The PP with the geolocators is best analysed as a comitative adjunct, though some would treat it as a complement of came".